# Laravel upload to Pagodabox

Tags: mysql, laravel, pagoda-box

I'm new to pagodabox.

I have connected my github project to pagodabox. I'm using Laravel 4 and I already created a database.

However, how can I upload my local database to pagodabox so my project can use it?

Here's my project http://dreary-doria.gopagoda.com/

Last is, what files I need to configure in my laravel project so that I can use it? As you can see when you check the link, it's just going to the root and not rendering the public directory.

Comment: Read Pagoda's documentation about app migrations, especially the database-related part : [Moving Your App to Pagoda Box](http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/256395-moving-your-app-to-pagoda-box). And for the Laravel configuration the only thing you'll need to change is the database credentials in `app/config/database.php`.

Comment: At first glance you've pushed a Laravel repository without a proper `Boxfile`, is your Github project public?